# ionic2:show html tags in <ion-content></ion-content

Tags: html, ionic2

I get html tags from serve,like this:

```
<fieldset><legend><b>Basic Info</b></legend><ul><li><label>ProjectName :</label><span>test project name</span></li><li><label>ProjectCode :</label><span>SZ201611</span></li><li><label>ProjectType :</label><span>SZ</span</fieldset><fieldset>
```

I prepared to show this in `<ion-content></ion-content>` like this:

```
<ion-content class="detail-style">
    <div [innerHTML]="html">
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

But the problem is the `<fieldset><legend>` tags have gone.That is when I look the source code with chrome browser,I found that fieldset and legend tags disappeared.It's like being filtered by innerTHML tag.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use `ng-bind-html` for binding html to DOM.

`<div
  ng-bind-html="expression">
</div>`

[ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: ionic 2 uses angular 2.. this looks like angularjs 1

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private sanitize: DomSanitizer){
}
......
this.html = this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
......
```

in html

```
<ion-content class="detail-style">
    <div [innerHTML]="html">
    </div>
</ion-content>
```